# Is it possible to use REPL clojure after download only clojure.jar from clojure.org site?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I've downloaded latest clojure jar file  from clojure.org site (Download section, clojure.1.10.1.jar) and try to run like below - always receiving exception.
Is it possible to run clojure based only on jar distributed on that site. If not - what should be provided yet? 
I don't want to download clojure tools - in some environment I have only possibility to run java with downloaded jars - nothing more.

**> java -jar clojure-1.10.1.jar**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2211)
        at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2220)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2239)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6839.invoke(core.clj:6126)
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/spec/alpha__init.class, clojure/spec/alpha.clj or clojure/spec/alpha.cljc on classpath.
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:462)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6839.invoke(core.clj:6126)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
```

and the same for 
**java -cp clojure-1.10.1.jar clojure.main**

Comment: See this page for the easiest way:  https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started

Comment: ...was going to say, I don't see a "download" link on the homepage at all.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I use Linux and Windows

On clojure is section menu option Release  and  there link "Download at Clojure 1.10.1" going to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.1/

Comment: See the POM at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.1/clojure-1.10.1.pom -- it tells you very explicitly that that jar isn't expected to work without also having `org.clojure/spec.alpha 0.2.176` and `org.clojure/core.specs.alpha 0.2.44`.

Comment: You can of course build an uberjar with all the dependencies built in, but the jar you linked to isn't such.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I understand. This is not what I expected. I don't understand why the Clojure authors present jar on the site, which is not full implementation of the language and even not explain that fact on page with the link. I'm new in Clojure world and want to start learning by using, but my enviroment is limited. It's first time when I see such situation. Maybe when I will know more about Clojure I will undertand the reasons, but digging in POM is not good idea for find answer for simple question.

Comment: Actually I think @nutilius is correct. For someone completely new, it's reasonable that most people will click on the large Get Started button, but a few will still click on Releases and then the second link on the Releases page takes you to the Maven repo, which is relevant for developers with experience with Maven or aware of the spec deps in Clojure 1.10. All that the Releases page needs is a banner that warns people that if you are new to the language, go to the Getting Started page.

Comment: @nutilus - for context: the exception you got is due to a decision not to pack 2 dependencies with the main jar. If you cannot download the dependencies with Maven, an option would be to download Clojure 1.8, which is old but still works with a single Jar without other dependencies.

Comment: My small comment yet - I'm not full time developer, rather sysadmin and system integrator working in different paltforms (partially even on Mainframe). Some environments have very limited access to the net and very often I work in isolated ecosystem. The JVM is present but very often without SDK (only runtime) and of course none  IDE. That is why I experiment with REPL languages like Scala and now Clojure. 
The Jython was very nice tool but today it is still on 2.7 Python level so I think about another tool. That is why I need to have "download and run" ecosystem.

Comment: Based on answer below I looked at pom file, downloaded two another jars and successfully run REPL. Unfortunatelly by mistake I joined this question to another thread (marked as dupicated) and cannot decribe that  solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to see the [Getting Started page](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started) at `clojure.org`. See also

- [Deps and CLI reference](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli)
- [Deps and CLI Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli)

I haven't tried Windows recently, but if you don't want to use the CLI/Deps approach it will probably be easier to set up a simple template project with Leiningen.

Install leiningen from this page:  https://leiningen.org/    Then test it:

```
> lein --version 
Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Assuming you already have Java and Git installed, clone [the following project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
> git clone https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template.git
> cd clj-template
> lein repl
```

---

### Update

If you have to transfer everything to a no-internet environment, it may be easiest to build a sample project on an internet-connect computer, then transfer both the project directory tree and your `~/.m2` directroy into the restricted environment.  The `~/.m2` dir is a local cache on your computer for all the library jar files needed by Maven to build various projects.  On my computer, this currently has over 260 entries.

Many Java & Clojure libraries have multiple, nested dependenies.  I think the easiest way to get a snapshot would be to build a representative project on the outside and then copy the `~/.m2` into the restriced env.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but I have to prepare standalone environment to transfer to isolated system without standard internet access. For example for scala I can just only transfer scala.jar and run it. 
No git access, no other internet acces in target os system. 

BTW I use Linux and Windows.

Comment: The `lein` tool that this answer points to can be used to build an uberjar, which you *then* can use on its own without needing anything else.